# Rank of a non-singular matrix not changes on pre or post multiplying with any other non-singular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

### Statement

"The rank of a matrix does not change by pre-multiplication 
or post multiplication with a non-singular matrix"

### Doubt

Now, Let P and Q are two non-singular matrices of rank M and N. Then as per the statement: 
on post multiplying Q with P : $ \rho(P*Q)= M $
 on pre-multiplying Q with P: $ ρ(Q*P)= M$  -------------(1)
Similarly, on post and pre multiplying P with Q:  $ρ(Q*P)= N$ and $ρ(Q*P)= N$  -----------(2)
**from 1 and 2,  M=N , which means every Non-singular matrix will have same rank**.
I know it's not correct, but where I am wrong ?

Comment: Hint, singular is defined using the determinant, i.e. only for square matrices, and two square matrices can only be multiplied if they have the same size

Comment: Okay, so does that means that every two non singular matrix which can be multiplied with each other will have same rank, and their product will also have  that same rank ?

Comment: Ohh.....Got it :(, 
I wasn't focusing on the "non-singular" part.
Thanks btw